# Strange crash when using for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I have an app that is creating and filling entities inside a

```
[[self managedObjectContext] performBlockAndWait
```

Inside this block I use a for loop to cycle through some data and create entities using this data.

**The strange part is :**
 If I use 
`for ( Entity in Array )` it will crash after about 10 iterations.  If I use the old `for ( int i = 0 i < array.count; i++)` and then access the array using `i` there is no crash.  The crash is a **signal SIGABRT**

Can anyone think of a reason why this crash would occur?

Comment: show your full code!

Comment: My guess would be undetected mutation of the array while looping.  Undetected by the enumerator, that is.

Comment: please show ur crash code

Comment: create a copy of your array and then try with that copy.

Comment: Maybe is a thread problem, are you accesing this array from other thread?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for ( Entity in array.length )
```

Comment: yikes.  no loop variable?  looping over an unsigned int?